# Eclipse "Run" Not finding the class

Tags: eclipse, minecraft

Trying to test my project with Eclipse's run, but it generates the following error:

```
Jul 31, 2013 9:32:50 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
INFO: Using tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
Jul 31, 2013 9:32:50 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
SEVERE: Unable to launch
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:49)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:18)
```

Yet

[image: Proof]

I try clicking the run from different places, yet it still doesn't work. Anyone know why?

Comment: Sounds like a classpath issue

Comment: classpath issue? Could you explain further?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshed my classpath by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> on the folder, thanks Adam.